# Validate nested json keys with list of keys

Tags: python, json, dataframe, validation, enumeration

I have list of valid keys
I have a nested json which I normalised into a df

After normalisation I end up with column names like "ItemProductContentWeightUoMGr"

In the list with valid keys I have an element called "UoM"

As you see I can't compare the two, which is what I am trying here:

```
try:
    for key in self.df.columns:
        if key not in self.valid_keys:
            raise KeyError(f'Key {key} is not present in list of valid keys')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Something went wrong validating the keys.\nError: {e}')
```

suppose df.columns can not be changed.. How could I do this validation of any nested json message against a simple list of keys?

Comment: How are you normalizing the input? Are you setting `sep` to something like an empty string? If you are validating the json, can you do so prior to loading it into a dataframe? Maybe with something like jmespath?

Comment: in this use case I already cleaned the df from the sep which was a "."

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to see what is actually logged within `e` for debugging in case of errors.
Anyways as I read your usecase there is no error or result as you would have to flip both "lists" of df.columns and valid_keys because you are looking to find a smaller pattern in a bigger string:

```
 for valid_key in valid_keys:
     if valid_key not in list(df.columns):
         ...
```